# Populate a DropdownList with composite key records in MVC3.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, composite-key

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but I really want to grab names of clients associated with a composite key.

Controller Code:

```
Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);


            ViewBag.jobClientsList = new SelectList(job.JobClients.ToList(), "ClientNumber", "ClientNumber");
```

View Code:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("ClientNumber", ViewData["JobClientsList"] as SelectList)%>
```

Model:

```
namespace Sample.CustomerService.Domain {
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class JobClient {
    public JobClient() { }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int JobNumber { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

}

This code works, but all I get in the dropdownlist is a bunch of numbers. What I would really like is the client names associated with the numbers but I'm really not sure how to do it! I've been looking around for ages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question your answer seems simpler then expected.
Check out the Select list class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx

The constructor your using in your controller is wrong, it should be:

```
ViewBag.jobClientsList = new SelectList(job.JobClients.ToList(), "ClientNumber", "Client");
```

You were setting the text value of the selectList to be "ClientNumber" which is why you had a list of numbers and not names!

Comment: I had realised this before reading your answer. But this is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default the select list is showing you the property that is marked [Key]

> <%: Html.DropDownList("ClientNumber",
>   ViewData["JobClientsList"].Client as SelectList)%>

Should print the client name (assuming the primary Key on the Client object is their name, otherwise You'd need something like `ViewData["JobClientsList"].Client.FullName`

The best solution would be to use a ViewModel instead of using ViewBag or ViewData for this, it'll help avoid a lot of headaches both now and in the future.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Client' and no extension method 'Client' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: I haven't used ViewData before, favoring ViewBag instead. If it said 'object' does not contain definition it's likely that you need to manually cast back into your class (JobClient) ViewData["JobClientsList"].Client

Comment: I have tried using ViewBag instead - <%: Html.DropDownList("ClientNumber", ViewBag.jobClientsList.Client.Name as SelectList)%>.          But error: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Client'

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past to get DropDownLists working is save the List to the Session Variable, and then create my SelectList in the actual DropDownList.
Controller:

```
Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id).ToList();  
ViewBag.jobClientList = job;
```

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("ClientNumber", new SelectList((If you view is strongly typed, put that here) ViewData["JobClientsList"],"ClientNumber","ClientNumber")%>
```

This may be poorly worded, so I think I can clarify if need be

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for a solution, try the following:

In your controller:

1) Get the list:

```
var allCountries = countryRepository.GetAllCountries();
```

2) define a variable:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

3)loop each item:

```
foreach(var country in allCountries)
 {
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() {
    Text = coutry.Name,
    Value = Country.Id.ToString(),
    // Put all sorts of business logic in here
    Selected = country.Id == 13 ? true : false
 });
}
```

model.Countries = items;

In your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("StringToDisplay", "actionName", "controllerName", new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value","Text"),"--Please Select--", new{@class="form-control"})
```

Not to mention Model should have a property with

```
public IEnumerable<Country> Countries {get; set;}
```