# ASP.NET MVC - create drop down list for a model that has composite primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to allow for selecting an item from list of items. The problem is that each item has a composite key, and if I use a drop down list, the value for each item is expected to be a string (but I need two strings for the composite key).

Right now, I've hacked it to combine the composite key into one string with a delimiting character in between when setting the list, and then parsing the value expecting the delimiting character when something is selected. Is there a cleaner/better way of achieving this? Obviously my current approach can fail if one of the keys already is using the same character.

Model:

```
public class CompositeKeyModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is this related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688744/populate-a-dropdownlist-with-composite-key-records-in-mvc3-net

Comment: @Biswabid No because in that question, they're treating it as a model with a single primary key.

Comment: I believe your approach is the right one, you just have to choose a delimiter reasonably unlikely to be used inside your `Name` or `Group` properties.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a `get` property to get the Value of the Property to retrive the composite Key

```
public class CompositeKeyModel
{
   [Key]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Key]
   public string Group { get; set; }

   public string CompositeKey {get
   {
      return Name+Group
   }}
}
```

Comment: Same issue as that's not necessarily unique. Think: Pen Island :)

Comment: so how is a composite key if the combination of them is not unique are?

Comment: can i have examples??